# Jump to first non-whitespace character in line in emacs

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I'm looking for the emacs equivalent of vi's `^`.

How can I move my cursor to the first non-whitespace character in a line?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48121/is-there-an-emacs-command-to-go-to-end-of-code-line-before-line-comment-and-whi/48160#48160

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The command is `back-to-indentation`, bound by default to <kbd>M-m</kbd>.

Answer (score 16):

This is what I picked up from [a previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145291/smart-home-in-emacs/145359):

```
(defun smart-beginning-of-line ()
  "Move point to first non-whitespace character or beginning-of-line.

Move point to the first non-whitespace character on this line.
If point was already at that position, move point to beginning of line."
  (interactive)
  (let ((oldpos (point)))
    (back-to-indentation)
    (and (= oldpos (point))
         (beginning-of-line))))
(global-set-key [home] 'smart-beginning-of-line)
(global-set-key "\C-a" 'smart-beginning-of-line)
```

Comment: this is not what the user asked for; ^ in vim does not do this; `M-m` is exactly the analog of `^` in vim and hence exactly the right answer.

Comment: @xdavidliu It does answer the user's question and does so in a really nice way by providing even more.

Comment: While not exactly what was asked, it gave me the answer I was looking for.  Nice to have this answer in a related question IMO.  Saved me more searching time.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [`crux`](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux)

type `C-a` to switch cursor between beginning of line and the first non-whitespace character

Comment: the question did not ask for toggling between first non-whitespace character and first column, it just asked for the analog of `^` in vim, which is exactly `M-m`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the mode you are using, for example on JS or TS mode you can use the TAB key, like if you were indenting a line.